# Formatting y-axis

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

How can I format monetary values ​​of the y-axis of my graph bar to be so:

```
R$ 123.456,00
```

Instead of:

```
R$ 123,456.00
```

Currently I'm using this function to format, but can't make this simple change:

```
var format = d3.format(',.2f'); // Need to change this, but don't know how

chart.yAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return "R$ " + format(d);
});
```

I've already searched in D3 documentation, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format method don't seems to allow custom thousands and decimal separators. I think that you should replace the symbols yourself:

```
var format = d3.format(',.2f');

// Format the number, adding thousands and decimal separators
var label = format(1234.00);

// Replace the . and the , symbols. The ! symbol is necessary to do the swap
// it can be other symbol though
label = label.replace('.', '!');
label = label.replace(',', '.');
label = label.replace('!', ',');

// The result is 'R$ 1.234,00'
d3.select('#chart').append('p').text('R$ ' + label);
```

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VuE3A/) have the replacement code.

Answer (score 2):

With d3 5.5 you can create a custom locale

https://github.com/d3/d3-format#formatLocale

Also note in the specifier(arg passed to .format) I now include a `$` This will automatically include the currency prefix in the formatted string.

```
const customD3Locale = d3.formatLocale({
  decimal: ",",
  thousands: ".",
  grouping: [3],
  currency: ["R$",""]
})

const format = customD3Locale.format('$,.2f');
```